# Handling multiple errors from a BatchUpdateException

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file, prepared-statement

I'm using a batch to insert lots of records in a database.
If any of them failed, I only get the record number (and the last exception message) in the update count array.

Is it possible to get all the error's causes?

I'm working with Java7 and Mysql connector (5.1.35). I also set the auto-commit to false.

Answer (score 0):

***Is it possible to get all the error's causes?***

Yes, it is possible.

> [BatchUpdateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html) is thrown when an error occurs during a batch update operation. It provides (among others) the update counts for all commands that were executed successfully during the batch update.
>
> The BatchUpdateException class is a subclass of SQLException, which represents an exception that provides information on a database access error or other errors.

### Catching a BatchUpdateException

BatchUpdateException should caught by the **last catch clause**, since it is a subclass of `SQLException`. You can manually catch it before it reaches the `SQLException`.

Below is the sample code

```
import java.sql.BatchUpdateException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CatchExceptionExample {
    
    private static final String HOST = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    private static final String DB = "db_test";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "bitnami";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `age`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST+DB,USER,PASSWORD);
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            
            ps.setInt(1,6);
            ps.setString(2, "Name1");
            ps.setString(3, "Surname1");
            ps.setInt(4, 1);
            ps.addBatch();
            
            ps.setInt(1,1);
            ps.setString(2, "Name1");
            ps.setString(3, "Surname1");
            ps.setInt(4, 1);
            ps.addBatch();
            
            int[] affectedRecords = ps.executeBatch();
            
        } catch (BatchUpdateException ex) {
            int[] updateCount = ex.getUpdateCounts();
            
            int count = 1;
            for (int i : updateCount) {
                if  (i == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
                    System.out.println("Error on request " + count +": Execute failed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Request " + count +": OK");
                }
                count++;
                
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For detail level explanation please visit [How to resolve Batch Update Exception](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/batchupdateexception/java-sql-batchupdateexception-how-to-resolve-batch-update-exception/) link. Also don't forget to read **More about BatchUpdateException** section of this article.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but actually my code looks that.
If I've got, for example, this update count array: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -3, 1, 1, -3], I'd like to know the causes of those two error (Duplicate key, wrong type, etc). 
In the batch update exception, I've could only find the cause of the last sentence...